# How can I extract the text between asterisks in Postgresql?

Tags: regex, postgresql, substring, postgresql-9.5

how can I extract the text between asterisks?

```
SELECT substring('QUITAR1 *W01 - 123456/9*  QUITAR2 ' from '%#"*_*#"_' for '#')
```

I need to retrieve the text the way: `W01 - 123456/9`

Postgresql 9.5.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use [substring with regular](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html), take asterix to square brackets:

```
t=# SELECT substring('QUITAR1 *W01 - 123456/9*  QUITAR2 ' from '%#"[*]%[*]#"%' for '#');
    substring
------------------
 *W01 - 123456/9*
(1 row)
```

so to get your wanted:

```
t=# SELECT replace(substring('QUITAR1 *W01 - 123456/9*  QUITAR2 ' from '%#"[*]%[*]#"%' for '#'),'*','');
    replace
----------------
 W01 - 123456/9
(1 row)
```

I'm using replace because having asterix in text would probably brake the mask anyway